# Input Checkbox Values to Array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a checkbox that I want its values to be outputted as an array, only values that are true. My problem is that its only outputting the true and false value. I want to output the `name` that its values are true as an array

Pls check my codesandbox here
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-checkbox-react-hooks-u038r)

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setCheckedItems({
      ...checkedItems,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked
    });
  };
  console.log(Object.values(checkedItems));
```

**EXPECTED SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
['check-box-1', 'check-box-2']
```

Comment: You should be able to access the name property on event.target. (event.target.name). Does that not work?

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're getting at if both boxes are checked, you would output the array ['check-box-1','check-box-2']?

Comment: I believe this should work `console.log(Object.entries(checkedItems).filter((record) => record[1]).map((record) => record[0]));`

Comment: @Andrew. Edited my question

Comment: @kmmanoj answered the question perfectly, and checking your code there is nothing more to be done. No need to "lessen" it. I hope kmmanoj will copy his comment to an answer so you can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are only logging the values: `console.log(Object.values(checkedItems));` not the actual state.

To view the actual state your log should be simply `console.log(checkedItems);`.

To see the desired output with just names your log should be `console.log(Object.keys(checkedItems));`

To get keys of only checked items:

```
console.log(Object.keys(checkedItems).filter(key => checkedItems[key]));
```

[image: Edit Multiple Checkbox React Hooks (forked)]

Comment: Thanks but I want to output only the values that are true

Comment: @Joseph `Object.keys(checkedItems).filter(key => checkedItems[key])`